# mysql-community-server5.7.18 conflicts file /etc/my.cnf with Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64

Tags: mysql, percona

When i tried to install percona-xtrabackup on Master server db 
**yum install percona-xtrabackup-24**

I got this error:
 file /etc/my.cnf from install of Percona-Server-shared-51-5.1.73-rel14.12.625.rhel6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-server-5.7.18-1.el6.x86_64

How to solve this problem?
-CentOS 6.5  2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Comment: remove? mysql-community is use for mysql server all process base on it.
after remove mysql service will down right?

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't see xtrabackup installation.

Comment: Can you try doing via rpm?  rpm -ivh https://www.percona.com/downloads/XtraBackup/Percona-XtraBackup-2.4.4/binary/redhat/7/x86_64/percona-xtrabackup-24-2.4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: i have tried but unluck!

Comment: are you getting same error?

Comment: yes. the same error

Comment: I have similar setup in rhel 7 but never encountered this error.

Comment: I can help you as a work around you may give it a try. Install the package on some other server and take innobackupexec file under /usr/bin to db server if you are planning to do with innobackupexec backup module. Execute a backup and see how it works.

Comment: @Mannoj ! i have tried to install mysql-server 5.1 on CeontOS 6.5 but i also never encountered this error. 
it seem problem with the version mysql-community-server 5.7.18 only

Answer (score 2):

try:

1. Download `mysql-community-libs-compat` from mysql (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

   ```
   rpm -i mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   ```
2. Install perl-DBD-MySQL

   ```
   yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
   ```
3. Install percona-xtrabackup

   ```
   yum install percona-xtrabackup
   ```